# get memory usage per process with sar, sysstat

Tags: linux, monitoring, sar

Can I get memory usage per process with Linux?
we monitor our servers with sysstat/sar. But besides
seeing that memory went off the roof at some point, we can't pinpoint
which process was getting bigger and bigger.
is there a way with sar (or other tools) to get memory usage
per process? and look at it, later on?

Comment: See also [How to view historical usage metrics, per process?](https://serverfault.com/questions/826825/how-to-view-historical-usage-metrics-per-process) on Server Fault

Answer (score 26):

`sysstat` includes `pidstat` whose man page says:

> The `pidstat` command is used for monitoring individual tasks currently being managed by the Linux kernel.  It writes to standard output activities for every task selected with option `-p`  or  for  every  task  managed  by the Linux kernel [...]

Linux kernel tasks include user-space processes and threads (and also kernel thread, which are of least interest here).

But unfortunately `sysstat` doesn't support collecting historical data from `pidstat` and it doesn't seems the author is interested in providing such support (GitHub issues):

- [[RFE] include pidstat data in sa data files](https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/issues/111)
- [pidstat: why no binary output option?](https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/issues/220)

## `pidstat`

That being said, tabular output of `pidstat` can be written to a file and later parsed. Typically groups of processes are of interest, rather than every process on the system. I'll focus on a process with its children processes.

What can be an example? Firefox. `pgrep firefox` returns its PID, `$(pgrep -d, -P $(pgrep firefox))` returns comma-separated list of its children. Given this, `pidstat` command can look like:

```
LC_NUMERIC=C.UTF-8 watch pidstat -dru -hl \
    -p '$(pgrep firefox),$(pgrep -d, -P $(pgrep firefox))' \
    10 60 '>>' firefox-$(date +%s).pidstat
```

Some observation:

- `LC_NUMERIC` is set to make `pidstat` use dot as the decimal separator.
- `watch` is used to repeat the `pidstat` every 600 seconds in case the
  process subtree changes.
- `-d` to *report I/O statistics*, `-r` to *report page faults and memory utilization*, `-u` to `report CPU utilization`.
- `-h` to make all report groups to be placed in one line, and `-l` to *display the process command name and all its arguments* (well, kind of, because it still trims it at 127 characters).
- `date` is used to avoid accidental overwrite of existing file

It produces something like:

```
Linux kernel version (host)     31/03/20    _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

#      Time   UID       PID    %usr %system  %guest    %CPU   CPU  minflt/s  majflt/s     VSZ     RSS   %MEM   kB_rd/s   kB_wr/s kB_ccwr/s iodelay  Command
 1585671289  1000      5173    0.50    0.30    0.00    0.80     5      0.70      0.00 3789880  509536   3.21      0.00     29.60      0.00       0  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox 
 1585671289  1000      5344    0.70    0.30    0.00    1.00     1      0.50      0.00 3914852  868596   5.48      0.00      0.00      0.00       0  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 ...
 1585671289  1000      5764    0.10    0.10    0.00    0.20     1      7.50      0.00 9374676  363984   2.29      0.00      0.00      0.00       0  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 ...
 1585671289  1000      5852    6.60    0.90    0.00    7.50     7    860.70      0.00 4276640 1040568   6.56      0.00      0.00      0.00       0  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 ...
 1585671289  1000     24556    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     7      0.00      0.00  419252   18520   0.12      0.00      0.00      0.00       0  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -parentBuildID ...

#      Time   UID       PID    %usr %system  %guest    %CPU   CPU  minflt/s  majflt/s     VSZ     RSS   %MEM   kB_rd/s   kB_wr/s kB_ccwr/s iodelay  Command
 1585671299  1000      5173    3.40    1.60    0.00    5.00     6      7.60      0.00 3789880  509768   3.21      0.00     20.00      0.00       0  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox 
 1585671299  1000      5344    5.70    1.30    0.00    7.00     6    410.10      0.00 3914852  869396   5.48      0.00      0.00      0.00       0  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 ...
 1585671299  1000      5764    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     3      0.00      0.00 9374676  363984   2.29      0.00      0.00      0.00       0  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 ...
 1585671299  1000      5852    1.00    0.30    0.00    1.30     1     90.20      0.00 4276640 1040452   6.56      0.00      0.00      0.00       0  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 ...
 1585671299  1000     24556    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     7      0.00      0.00  419252   18520   0.12      0.00      0.00      0.00       0  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -parentBuildID ...

...
```

Note that each line with data starts with a space, so parsing is easy:

```
import pandas as pd

def read_columns(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for l in f:
            if l[0] != '#':
                continue
            else:
                return l.strip('#').split()
        else:
            raise LookupError

def get_lines(filename, colnum):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for l in f:
            if l[0] == ' ':
                yield l.split(maxsplit=colnum - 1)        

filename = '/path/to/firefox.pidstat'
columns = read_columns(filename)
exclude = 'CPU', 'UID', 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    get_lines(filename, len(columns)), columns=columns, exclude=exclude
)
numcols = df.columns.drop('Command')
df[numcols] = df[numcols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df['RSS'] = df.RSS / 1024  # Make MiB
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], unit='s', utc=True)
df = df.set_index('Time')
df.info()
```

The structure of the dataframe is as follows:

```
Data columns (total 15 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   PID        6155 non-null   int64  
 1   %usr       6155 non-null   float64
 2   %system    6155 non-null   float64
 3   %guest     6155 non-null   float64
 4   %CPU       6155 non-null   float64
 5   minflt/s   6155 non-null   float64
 6   majflt/s   6155 non-null   float64
 7   VSZ        6155 non-null   int64  
 8   RSS        6155 non-null   float64
 9   %MEM       6155 non-null   float64
 10  kB_rd/s    6155 non-null   float64
 11  kB_wr/s    6155 non-null   float64
 12  kB_ccwr/s  6155 non-null   float64
 13  iodelay    6155 non-null   int64  
 14  Command    6155 non-null   object 
dtypes: float64(11), int64(3), object(1)
```

It can be visualised in many ways that depend on what the focus of the monitoring is, but `%CPU` and `RSS` are the most common metrics to look at. So here is an example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(df.PID.unique()), 2, figsize=(12, 8))
x_range = [df.index.min(), df.index.max()]
for i, pid in enumerate(df.PID.unique()):
    subdf = df[df.PID == pid]
    title = ', '.join([f'PID {pid}', str(subdf.index.max() - subdf.index.min())])
    for j, col in enumerate(('%CPU', 'RSS')):
        ax = subdf.plot(
            y=col, title=title if j == 0 else None, ax=axes[i][j], sharex=True
       )
        ax.legend(loc='upper right')
        ax.set_xlim(x_range)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

It produces a figure like:

[image: firefox subprocess tree]

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 I see this error, How can I proceed ?
 
File "./pd_plot.py", line 40
    title = ', '.join([f 'PID {pid}', str(subdf.index.max() - subdf.index.min())])
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9

Comment: Make sure you copy-pasted the snippets correctly. There's definitely no space between f-string prefix and the string itself above, i.e. `f 'PID...'` is invalid syntax, that's why you get `SyntaxError`. You can also take a look at a couple of ready-made tools for visualisation of Linux process resource utilisation over time in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414770/124219).

Answer (score 2):

This is purely preference but I would keep it nice and simple until you know what you're looking for. I would create a `cronjob` to first pipe out your free memory, disk and cpu usage and then to display the top ten culprits.

```
#!/bin/sh
free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'
df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)\n", $3,$2,$5}'
top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf "CPU Load: %.2f\n", $(NF-2)}' 
ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head
```

After finding your culprit, you can hone in a little more and dig into some specifics.